# what happens when we try to pass a function as a argument to the same function?

Tags: c

When I'm running the following program i'm getting the output as 1.00000. But my doubt is that how that function works? I'm not very sure about its working. Please let me know the working process of the below code

```
float avg(float,float,float);

int main() 
{ 
    float p=1,q=2,r=-2,a;
    a=avg(p,(q=4,r=-12,q),r); 
    printf("%f",a); 
    return 0; 
} 

float avg(float x,float y,float z) 
{
    return (x+y+z)/3; 
}
```

Comment: you are not passing a function to a function, just assigning values to q and r

Comment: but how do i get the output as 1.000000

Answer (score 8):

There is no function call within function call.

In,

```
a=avg(p,(q=4,r=-12,q),r);
```

the code:

```
(q=4,r=-12,q)
```

assigns `q = 4`, `r = -12` and passes `q` as the second argument.More on this later<sup>[Note:1]</sup>

Note that the order of evaluation of arguments to a function is **Unspecified**.
Which means that the arguments can be passed to the function in order:

- **Case 1:** Left to Right or
- **Case 2:** Right to Left or
- **Case 3:** Any magical order which compiler wants(ofcourse this is only possible if no of arguments is more than 2)

In your example, If your compiler choses:

- **Case 1**, then output will be `-2.....`
- **Case 2** then output will be `1`.
- **Case 3** then output can be magical

As you have seen from your code example, it is best to not write any such code which produces [**side effects**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8a425116%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

---

<sup>[Note:1]</sup>

The meaning of comma operator(`,`) in the expression:

```
(e1,e2,e3)
```

is:

> Evaluate the subexpression `e1`, then evaluate `e2` and then evaluate `e3`. The value of the expression is the value of `e3`.

Comment: Okay. But thus does not calls the function twice???

Comment: @Praveen: No, it doesn't, added more explanation hope that helps.

Comment: i can't able to understand....explain me clearly

Comment: @Praveen: I have explained the best I could so Help me help you by asking the right Qs.

Answer (score 1):

You can get 1 as the output if x+y+z = 3. We know that x is 1, so y+z = 2. This is possible if q = 4 and r = -2. Since evaluation order is undefined, then we can conclude that the compiler is evaluating the arguments from right to left.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are not getting compiler warning? If not, enable `-Wall` (for gcc compiler).

> > a=avg(p,(q=4,r=-12,q),r);

The first argument in this function call is of type `float (float,float,float)` NOT `float`, as per the function is defined. You are supposed to get a compiler warning.

The first argument is pointer to the function `avg`; There is no function call.